How to configure two server domains in django-anymail
I'm working on a Django project and using Anymail with Mailgun to send emails.
I have two domains pointing to same site domain1.com and domain2.com
I set up mailgun both senver domains as mg.domain1.com and mg.domain2.com both with their api key.
Both domains worked fine when set as default domain senders.
I need to send client email and switch them depending if they are users of domain1 or domain2. Because I want the serder email will be noreply@domain1.com and noreply@domain2.com depending on the user.
In my settings.py, I have the following configuration:
ANYMAIL = {
    'MAILGUN_API_KEY': API_KEY_DOMAIN1,
    'MAILGUN_SENDER_DOMAIN': SENDER_DOMAIN_1'],
}

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'anymail.backends.mailgun.EmailBackend'
SERVER_EMAIL = noreply@domain1.com
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = Domain 1 <noreply@domain1.com>

Here is send email code:
email = AnymailMessage(
    to=message.to.split(','),
    cc=message.cc.split(',') if message.cc else None,
    bcc=message.bcc.split(',') if message.bcc else None,
    reply_to=None,
    subject=message.notification.subject,
    body=message.notification.body_text,
    from_email=message.from_email,
)
email.attach_alternative(message.notification.body_html, 'text/html')

if user.brand['name'] == 'domain2':
    email.esp_extra = {
        'sender_domain': SENDER_DOMAIN_2,
        'api_key': API_KEY_DOMAIN2,
    }

try:
    email.send()
except Exception as e:
    print('Error sending email:', e)

As you can see. I try to use esp_extra to switch between sender domain, but I get:
anymail.exceptions.AnymailRequestsAPIError: Mailgun API response 401 (Unauthorized): 'Forbidden'

What could be causing this issue, and how can I resolve it?

Anymail's esp_extra must contain fields from Mailgun's send an email API request body (when using Anymail's Mailgun EmailBackend). 'sender_domain' and 'api_key' are not valid fields for Mailgun's API, which is why your request is failing.
To override settings for a particular message, one approach is to create your own connection using Django's get_connection():
from django.core.mail import get_connection

email = AnymailMessage(...)  # your code as before

if user.brand['name'] == 'domain2':
    # Override the connection for this message
    email.connection = get_connection(
        "anymail.backends.mailgun.EmailBackend",
        api_key=API_KEY_DOMAIN2,
        sender_domain=SENDER_DOMAIN_2,
    )

email.send()  # as before

(There's an example of this in Anymail's docs.)
Also, by default Anymail uses the domain of the from_email as the sender domain. If your from_email is always set to someone@domain1.com or someone@domain2.com, then you can let Anymail auto-detect the sender domain: get rid of the "MAILGUN_SENDER_DOMAIN" setting and skip the sender_domain part of the code above.
